# How to get body text in libcurl multipart/form_data?

Tags: http, libcurl

After I used C++ libcurl library to generate a multipart/form_data request, I need to calculate a sign value from the body text. But i could not find an API to get the body text. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the undocumented Curl_mime functions in lib/curl/mime.h on your own risk. The functions can be changed or removed in the future.

```
curl_mimepart part = {0};
Curl_mime_set_subparts(&part, mime, false);
curl_off_t size = Curl_mime_size(&part);
char* data = malloc(size);
Curl_mime_read(data, 1, size, &part);
free(data);
```

Comment: Thanks! How can i include this header? I could not find it under my system curl header directory `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl/`.

Comment: You should use the header from libcurl sources for the same version of your libcurl.